# transferring files with spaces in them with putty's pscp

Tags: windows-7, linux, putty, scp, pscp

I tried the following to no avail:

```
pscp -load test username username@domain.tld:"file name.ext" "file name.ext"

pscp -load test username "username@domain.tld:file name.ext" "file name.ext"

pscp -load test username username@domain.tld:"file\ name.ext" "file name.ext"

pscp -load test username "username@domain.tld:file\ name.ext" "file\ name.ext"

pscp -load test username username@domain.tld:"c:\\path\to\\file\ name.ext" "/home/username/file\ name.ext"

pscp -load test username "username@domain.tld:c:\\path\to\\file\ name.ext" "/home/username/file\ name.ext"
```

Both returned me a `More than one remote source not supported` error.

Is it just not possible?

Comment: With Cygwin `scp` I normally quote _and_ escape the spaces, which seems to work. eg. `'file\ name.txt'` Putty's `pscp` might be similar.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( I updated my orig post to include my attempts with the escaped space.

Comment: I think you have to specify the path also. eg. `username@domain.tld:/path/to/file\ name.ext`.

Comment: No luck. See my updated post.

Comment: The username and host should be on the target eg. `pscp -load test "c:\path\to\file name.ext" "username@domain.tld:/home/username/file\ name.ext"` You're already logged into Windows, so you don't need to specify local credentials. And you don't need to escape the space for the Windows filename.

Comment: @neubert, are both machines Windows or is the remote machine *nix?

Comment: @neubert, also, can you successfully transfer a file _without_ spaces in the filename?

Comment: @Mike Fitzpatrick - I can indeed transfer without spaces. It's spaces that cause the problem. The machine I'm downloading to is Windows. The one I'm downloading from is Ubuntu. And the command you proposed is for uploading, not for downloading.